# SqlDataSource lost the where clause during paging

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I have a `SqlDataSource` with this query:

```
SELECT [ProductName], [Debscription], [Price] FROM [MyDb] WHERE ([Date1] >= @Date1) ORDER BY [ProductName]">
```

When I load the page, it works fine and shows me only the products that I want.
When I try changing page of the `GridView`, and for example, go to page 2, it refreshes the page and generates lots of page indexes as the where clause is lost.

How can I solve this?

I thought that the statement was automatically saved, but it's not.

How can I save the where clause during paging?

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic paging you should use an ObjectDataSource instead of a SqlDataSource.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the grid to handle paging, bind it to a DataTable or DataSet. For ex:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   if (!Page.IsPostBack)
       BindData();
}

private void BindData()
{
    // Connect to the Database
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connection string);

    // Retrieve the SQL query results and bind it to the DataGrid
    string SQL_QUERY = "SELECT ProductName, UnitPrice, UnitsInStock " +
                  "FROM Products";
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(SQL_QUERY, myConnection);

    // Use a DataTable – required for default paging
    SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);

    DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
    myAdapter.Fill(myTable);

    dgProducts.DataSource = myTable;
    dgProducts.DataBind();
    myConnection.Close();
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479006.aspx

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16419576)

Comment: I wasn't sure if the original answer/link answered the question exactly so I skipped the code. Updated with code.